# Some doubts about declarative meaning of a program that prints a list of lists in Prolog

Tags: prolog

> Write a rule that take a list whose elements are themselves lists and
>   print on each line the elements of internals list:
>
> Example:
>
> **?- printList[[1,a],[2,b]]).**
>
> **1 a**
>
> **2 b**

The solution it the following one:

```
/* BASE CASE: The list is empty, so there is nothing to print */
printList([]).

printList([P|R]):- printList(P),
                   !,
                   nl,
                   printList(R).

printList([X|R]):- write(X),
                   !,
                   printList(R).
```

I have the printList rule that reaches the base case when the list is empty and in this case there is nothing to print.

If I am not in the base case (the list is not empty) it calls the second rule **printList([P|R])** and now I have my first doubt:

The element P is a list because Prolog automatically handles an internal list as an element?

So, If I have something like:

**[[1,a],[2,b],[3,c],[4,d]]** I have that Prolog automatically match in this way:

**P = [1,a]** (the first list as the head element)

**R = [[2,b],[3,c],[4,d]]** (the other 3 list are the element of a tail list)

And then the program calls the **printList** predicate on the head element (the first list) and this version of the rule writes all the elements in the current list.

Is this right this interpretation?

Now I have some doubts about about the trace of this program, for example if I execute this statement I obtain the following trace:

```
[trace]  ?- printList([[1,a], [2,b]]).
   Call: (6) printList([[1, a], [2, b]]) ? creep
   Call: (7) printList([1, a]) ? creep
   Call: (8) printList(1) ? creep
   Fail: (8) printList(1) ? creep
   Redo: (7) printList([1, a]) ? creep
   Call: (8) write(1) ? creep
1
   Exit: (8) write(1) ? creep
   Call: (8) printList([a]) ? creep
   Call: (9) printList(a) ? creep
   Fail: (9) printList(a) ? creep
   Redo: (8) printList([a]) ? creep
   Call: (9) write(a) ? creep
a
   Exit: (9) write(a) ? creep
   Call: (9) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) printList([a]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) printList([1, a]) ? creep
   Call: (7) nl ? creep

   Exit: (7) nl ? creep
   Call: (7) printList([[2, b]]) ? creep
   Call: (8) printList([2, b]) ? creep
   Call: (9) printList(2) ? creep
   Fail: (9) printList(2) ? creep
   Redo: (8) printList([2, b]) ? creep
   Call: (9) write(2) ? creep
2
   Exit: (9) write(2) ? creep
   Call: (9) printList([b]) ? creep
   Call: (10) printList(b) ? creep
   Fail: (10) printList(b) ? creep
   Redo: (9) printList([b]) ? creep
   Call: (10) write(b) ? creep
b
   Exit: (10) write(b) ? creep
   Call: (10) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (10) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (9) printList([b]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) printList([2, b]) ? creep
   Call: (8) nl ? creep

   Exit: (8) nl ? creep
   Call: (8) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (8) printList([]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) printList([[2, b]]) ? creep
   Exit: (6) printList([[1, a], [2, b]]) ? creep
true.
```

This is quite clear for me (I think that my previous reasoning is right) but I am not understanding why whenever it reaches an element in an internal list it calls the **printList** relation on it (that is a simple element and not a list), for example here:

```
   Call: (8) printList(1) ? creep
   Fail: (8) printList(1) ? creep
```

the program had considered the first list of the original list and then, into it to have to print its first element, why call the **printList** relation on this **simple element**

Is it because this simple element may in turn be internal lists?

Something like:

**[[[1.1,a1,a2],[1.2,b1,b2]], [2,b]]** (in which I have a list that contains 2 lists and the first element it is a list that contains 2 lists. So the program checks if an element it is an element or an internal list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're over-thinking it. Look at the code:

```
printList([P|R]):- printList(P),
```

Right there you can see that `printList/1` is being unified with the head of the list. The fact that all the rules of `printList/1` match lists and only lists is a fact that you, the human, can immediately see. But Prolog does not "notice" this fact, so if you are to call, say,

```
printList([1])
```

the first matching rule is the one above, so it will immediately try to unify `printList(1)`. This will fail, naturally, because 1 is not a list and so doesn't match any of the rules for `printList/1`. Prolog then backtracks and tries the next rule, which is the one that starts like this:

```
printList([X|R]):- write(X),
```

This is clearly going to unify [1] with X = 1, R = [], so it's clearly going to write the first element, the one, and then proceed as usual. There is no magic here involving "internal lists," which as far as I'm aware is not a concept in Prolog at all (if such a thing is treated in the compiler it is well hidden from the user of Prolog).

Prolog isn't psychic; it has to try the rules to see if they fail, even if that attempt is essentially a failing pattern-match in the head of the Horn clause.

I am unable to distinguish your first from your second question so I hope this answers both. :)